# Bootstrap datetimepicker display issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have an issue with invalid display of Bootstrap datetimepicker. I have probably some styles mixed out but I cannot figure it out where is the issue. Below there are screenshots how my datetimepicker is displayed. As can be seen, icon for "hours" is on the left and when I click on it, I can only see hours and not minutes.

[image]

[image]

I initialize event as follows:

```
$('#NewEvent_TimeOfReminding').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'pl',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'
});
```

Comment: I think its CSS issues. Probably somewhere in your styles you are overriding some selector that's used by the datetimepicker which is messing up the look of it.

Comment: Yes I know that, the question is...which style is it?

Comment: How can i know without seeing the code?

Comment: MM is only used for months with a leading zero, and you have used it for minutes as well. Try YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm

Comment: It doesn't work as well..

Comment: You could try setting the options `keepOpen` or `inline` to true to make it easier to inspect the CSS and troubleshoot what is going on. From just a screenshot there is no definitive way to diagnose this, but if I was to guess it would be some of your custom/3rd party CSS related to `table` or `td`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this yourself, I recommend using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome Developer Tools to inspect the CSS being applied. Try to look for CSS being applied which is not sourced from Bootstrap CSS files. You may need to traverse the element hierarchy somewhat to find the point at which the wrong CSS is being applied.

If you can't find a solution, then you will need to either:

- Provide more detail (a lot) on what CSS your page has, html structure, etc.
- Or even better, create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that showcases the problem.